# Android Bluetooth output audio

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth

I want my Android device to behave as a Bluetooth speaker

All solutions possible welcomed, whatever it needs (stock, BL unlock, root, systemless, xposed, idk).

Reason: Redirect all computer audio to Android audio output.

Comment: Please post some specs for the device, android version, if rooted, and a reason - that can help tailor the answer.

Comment: You might find an app that can expose your phone's speaker via DLNA. Maybe something that does this in reverse: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.al.dlnaserver&hl=en&gl=US&pli=1

Comment: @RohitGupta I can tailor my device to solution needs. Biggest problem for now to have a solution at all. @\Marcel good idea, many apps permit to read DLNA stream. Maybe not so much that permit to make a DLNA stream